# Pagination and group by for Custom views created using list definition not working

Tags: list-definition, list-view

I created a list using the list definition + list instance from VS 2010. I also created the list views for the list. When I add Group by and paging properties for custom views other than All Items view then it is not updating the paging and group by properties for custom views.

Here is my view section in schema.xml:

```
<Views>
  <View Name="{0D99F290-8885-460B-B5D9-89DE354C53E7}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="All Items" Url="Lists/ArbitrationDecisions/AllItems.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="Property_x0020_Type"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
  <View Name="{13F09AAA-C7B3-4807-92F7-F277134D6ECD}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="All By Hotel name" Url="Lists/ArbitrationDecisions/All By Hotel name.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
        <FieldRef Name="Title"/>
      </GroupBy>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="LinkTitle"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
  <View Name="{50A610E7-03C9-43DD-997C-499C069FDC12}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="By Hotel Status" Url="Lists/ArbitrationDecisions/By Hotel Status.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
        <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      </GroupBy>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="LinkTitle"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
  <View Name="{DE967002-08CD-4BEE-9140-3D39829F7C64}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="By Hotel Union" Url="Lists/ArbitrationDecisions/By Hotel Union.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
        <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      </GroupBy>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="LinkTitle"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
  <View Name="{0BE3F0A4-BCEC-4185-A3D1-8E9EAEACB767}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="By Local number" Url="Lists/ArbitrationDecisions/By Local number.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30">
        <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      </GroupBy>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="LinkTitle"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
  <View Name="{48C45BFF-EBD1-473E-B03E-8609B691A9F3}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="Summary" Url="Lists/ArbitrationDecisions/Summary.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">3</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="LinkTitle"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
  <View Name="{9607DFEE-43B8-431C-A5CE-EEEDF333BA90}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="" Url="Pages/Application.aspx" Level="255" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png">
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="Attachments"/>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Property_x0020_Type"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Hotel_x0020_Status"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Union"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Local_x0020_Number"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Comments"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">3</RowLimit>
    <Mobile MobileItemLimit="3" MobileSimpleViewField="LinkTitle"/>
    <XslLink>main.xsl</XslLink>
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
  </View>
</Views>
```

I'm using SharePoint Online.